# Is there any possible solution to use MSBuild with C++ projects and conditional compilation statements?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, c-preprocessor

My problem:
I have created a **C** project in Visual Studio 2010 and defined a conditional compilation constant named `QWERTY`. My **C** source code executes `#ifdef QWERTY` in order to see if it's defined or not.
When I add `/DQWERTY` into the command line additional options of my **C** project in the IDE, then the constant is correctly detected after compilation, just as expected.

So, my questions is: how can I define that constant from the command line using MSBuild?

Just for clarity reasons, I'm running this command:

```
MSBuild myproj.sln
```

Please don't propose to use the switch `/p:DefineConstants`; I've created a **C** project, not a C# project, and that switch is useless for C/C++ projects.

As you've probably already understood, I'm feeling more and more desperate about this trivial problem. Please enlighten me and show me that there is a simple solution around the corner that I've missed of pure stupidity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MSBuild.exe not accepting either /p:DefineConstants nor /p:PreprocessorDefinitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016697/msbuild-exe-not-accepting-either-pdefineconstants-nor-ppreprocessordefinition)

Comment: have you tried `set CL=/DQWERTY`

Comment: Ah, very brutal solution, but yet effective.
Nice. It works. I would have preferred some injection support through MSBuild, but your solution work as well. Most important, it solves my problem.
Thank you smerlin.