# Passing preprocessor variable to nmake build environment

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, visual-studio-2005, nmake, wdk

I am having issues with building driver using `nmake` on Win7 x64 build environment. I am defining a preprocessor variable and passing it over the command line using -

```
build /nmake "USER_C_FLAGS=/DMyVersion=3"
```

And the build log is -

```
...
/DMyVersion=3
/typedil- 
/wd4603
/wd4627
....
```

So, I clearly see the variable as part of the compiler options. Now in a header fie, I do

```
#define otherVersion 10
#ifdef MyVersion
  #undef otherVersion
  #define otherVersion MyVersion
#endif

#define FileVersion otherVersion
```

The problem is `FileVersion` is always being **10** irrespective of the `MyVersion` define passed and exist in the environment. To test, what is going on, I did -

```
#ifdef MyVersion
  #error MyVersion is present in the environment.
#endif
```

I see the statement being printed. But why is `otherVersion` is always **10** despite the preprocessor directive is present in the environment ? Why it is not taking the value **3** passed via command line options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, if this works for you, but some people did try to achieve quite the same using msbuild. They had to adapt the project-file to pipe their definitions "into" the build-process. Have a look at [MSBuild.exe not accepting either /p:DefineConstants nor /p:PreprocessorDefinitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016697/msbuild-exe-not-accepting-either-pdefineconstants-nor-ppreprocessordefinitio)