# Pass macro to nmake

Tags: c++, msbuild, nmake, wdk, makefile

From [my earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988501/passing-preprocessor-variable-to-nmake-build-environment), I figured out why the command

```
build /nmake "USER_C_FLAGS=/DMyVersion=3"
```

doesn't associate the define `MyVersion` with value **3**. [MSDN says that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) -

> Compiling with /Dname= causes the symbol to not have an associated
>   value. So, while the symbol can still be used to conditionally compile
>   code, the symbol will otherwise evaluate to nothing. For example, in
>   the previous sample program, compiling with /DTEST= will cause a
>   compiler error. This behavior is similar to using #define with or
>   without a value.

I have an environment variable that gets set up at run-time and I need to pass that env. variable to the **Visual Studio 2005 Makefile Project**. Now the question is, how can I pass the env. variable to the run-time build environment ? Once passed, I should be able to something like -

```
#define VERSION 11

#ifdef BUILD_VERSION       // How to get this macro to the current env. ?
   #undef VERSION
   #define VERSION BUILD_VERSION
#endif

#define FILE_VERSION VERSION
```

I don't see any flags from `nmake` documentation to pass env. variables. Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: I think the manual part you quote is for defining macros without contents, i.e. a literal "`/DMACRO=`", which is the same as "`/DMACRO`". Your example should work. Maybe you can post the relevant parts of your makefile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN will answer this for nmake [Environment-Variable Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/99at5bh3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Pay attention here: "Use the /E option to cause macros inherited from environment variables to override any macros with the same name in the makefile."