# How to use the MSBuild command line parameter called Configuration as a conditional compilation symbol?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I would like to display a string that tells user which build configuration was used to build the application. For example:

If the command line resembled this:

```
msbuild project.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release
```

And then in the source code, I would like to do this:

```
Console.Writeline("You are running the " + <get the /p:Configuration value> + " version" );
```

The user would see this:

> You are running the Release version

I know that we can declare conditional compilation symbols (#defines) at the command prompt such as how it is defined [in this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016697/msbuild-exe-not-accepting-either-pdefineconstants-nor-ppreprocessordefinitio) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714668/how-do-you-pass-conditional-compilation-symbols-defineconstants-to-msbuild). But I want to use the existing variable called `Configuration`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no way to do this, except as you said = using #if. MSBuild configuration name is just a name for set of configurations in project file to build specific flavor of your project. By default you do not have access to this configuration name from your code.

I see two ways how you can change the string in your code:

a) As you said - you can specify the conditional compilation symbols, so you can do something like

```
#if DEBUG
const string Flavor = "Debug";
#else
const string Flavor = "Release";
#endif
...
Console.WriteLine("You are running the " + Flavor + " version" );
```

b) You can play with your project file and include different set of files depending on the Configuration. If you will unload your project and open csproj as just a file - you will see for example

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="MyApp.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

You can change to something like:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="MyApp.Release.cs" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'" />
  <Compile Include="MyApp.Debug.cs" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'" />
</ItemGroup>
```

So this is how you will include different set of files for each configuration, where you can specify what configuration user has right now.

Comment: Side note, the compilation symbol DEBUG doesn't necessarily mean "Debug configuration"; the debug configuration typically sets this flag, but it's not forced to.

Comment: I liked your second solution. I have several (more than 2) configurations. Great idea! Thanks!

Comment: is there a way to still get the Configuration-value in the C# code?